# Unity shader: Parser error: syntax error at line 19

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, shader

I was making a shader script in Unity and I got a syntax error.
I don't see any mistake in there, though.
Does anyone else see the trouble maker?

```
Shader "Custom/Toon" {
    Properties {
            ...
        _OutlineColor ("Outline Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
            ...
    }
    SubShader {
        Pass {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardBase" }
            GLSLPROGRAM
            ...
            uniform vec4 _OutlineColor; //Line 19
            ...
```

Comment: use float4 instead of vec4 ?

Comment: Same error plus two more.

Comment: Oh right, here are the errors I get:

Shader error in 'Custom/Toon': Parse error: syntax error at line 19
Shader error in 'Custom/Toon': ERROR: 0:20: error(#132) Syntax error: '_OutlineColor' parse error at line 20
Shader error in 'Custom/Toon': See Temp\vsShader00_0.txt (compiling for cafe) at line 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
All I had to do is changing "GLSLPROGRAM" and "ENDGLSL" into "CGPROGRAM" and "ENDCG".